Gaussian 16 input syntax error with Last state= "IOpZ"
While trying to run an input file which contains the following:
...
%mem=500GB
%NProcShared=48
# oniom(CCSD(maxcyc=250)/aug-cc-pvdz:b3lyp/cc-pvdz) opt(MaxCycle=999) scf(maxcycle=999)
freq EmpiricalDispersion=GD3
IOp(3/174=1.0) IOp(3/175=1.7030) IOp(3/176=1.2610)

I'm getting the following error:
...
 QPErr --- A syntax error was detected in the input line.
 spersion=GD3 IOp(3/174=1.0) IOp(3/175=1.
                         '
 Last state= "IOpZ"
 TCursr=    177329 LCursr=       128
...

I'll be most thankful for any help in the matter.

The IOp values are always integers. While they might get converted internally into floating point numbers, this is typically done by taking a integer with a particular format and applying a scaling factor. For example, here is the description of IOp(3/174) from the Gaussian website:
IOp(3/174)

S6 scale factor in Grimme’s D2/D3/D3BJ dispersion.

0   Default (see subroutine R6DS6).
-1  Set S6 to 0.
NNNNNNNN    A value of NNNNNNNN/1000000.

So if you want to set this scale factor to $1.0$, you need to enter iop(3/174=1000000) since the value you enter will be divided by $1000000$.
